# How to set Spatial parameters in SoleQuery.java of com.github.takezoe.solr.scala

Tags: solr

We need to set spatial fields like pt, field, and d programmatically. we are using solr library 7.1.0. Looking at the SolrQuery class methods it seems it doesn't have any support to enable spatial query and add spatial parameters. Here is the parameter list which I want to set in my query. Any idea how I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [use `solrQuery.set("fieldname", "value")` to supply custom parameters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams.html#set-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-):

```
solrQuery.set("pt", "-34...");
solrQuery.set("sfield", "location");
```

These can also usually be given in your query if you're using `{!geofilt` or similar: `{!geofilt sfield=location}`.

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh